# Como fazer uma datagridview C# ordenar uma lista (IList) com click no cabeçalho da grid?

Tags: c#, linq, select, classificação, datagridview

Como fazer uma **DataGridView** C# ordenar uma lista (IList) com click no cabeçalho da grid?

Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com três campos (id, nome, cidade), quando o usuario clicar na coluna nome, quero que ordene pelo Nome, se clicar na cidade quero que ordene por Cidade.

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Usando IList pessoas;

Usando o click do cabecalho da coluna na Grid.

Comment: Onde está a pergunta? O site funciona diferente de fórum. Se você quiser compartilhar algo que tenha feito, precisa fazer no formato que é demonstrado no **[tour]**

Comment: Ola @diegofm, sou novo aqui no site, obrigado pela dica, os próximos posts vou colocar as perguntas, separados das respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Se você criar um `dataTable` você não precisa se "preocupar" com isto

Esta função converte sua lista para o `datatable`, você precisa instalar este pacote via nuget, [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/), pois usa o `TypeAccessor`.

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable(this IList source, String nameColumnPK)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    var table = new DataTable();
    if (source.Count == 0) return table;

    Type itemType = source[0].GetType();
    table.TableName = itemType.Name;
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    foreach (var prop in itemType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.CanRead && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            names.Add(prop.Name);
            Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
            if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                propType = propType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(prop.Name, propType);
            table.Columns.Add(column);
            if (nameColumnPK != null && nameColumnPK == prop.Name)
                table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { column };
        }
    }
    names.TrimExcess();

    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(itemType);
    object[] values = new object[names.Count];
    foreach (var row in source)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
           values[i] = accessor[row, names[i]];
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return table;
}
```

e crie esta extensão:

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(this IList source, Expression<Func<T, object>>  columnPK)
{
    String member = ((columnPK.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    return ConvertToDatatable(source, member);
}
```

e então é só fazer isto no seu programa

```
 listaTeste = new List<Teste>();
 listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 1, Nome = "Maria", Cidade = "São Paulo" });
 listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 2, Nome = "Luiza", Cidade = "Curitiba" });
 listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 3, Nome = "Ana", Cidade = "Porto Alegre" });

 dataGridView1.DataSource = listaTeste.ConvertToDatatable<Teste>(t => t.id);

//o `sort` vai funcionar normalmente, para Id, Nome e Cidade
```

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de compartilhar a solução que achei: Segue exemplo.

No ColumnHeaderMouseClick coloquei um select na lista usando um campo criado no modelo apenas para consulta, neste select alimento o campo "consulta" com a informação do campo que quero ordenar e logo em seguida ordeno pelo campo consulta.

```
Achei que seria útil compartilhar, segue Exemplo:

    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IList<Teste> listaTeste;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listaTeste = new List<Teste>();
        listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 1, Nome = "Maria", Cidade = "São Paulo" });
        listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 2, Nome = "Luiza", Cidade = "Curitiba" });
        listaTeste.Add(new Teste() { Id = 3, Nome = "Ana", Cidade = "Porto Alegre" });

        var lista = listaTeste.Select(s => new { Id = s.Id, Nome = s.Nome, Cidade = s.Cidade, Consulta = s.GetType().GetProperty("Nome").GetValue(s) }).OrderBy(x => x.Consulta).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista ;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        var lista = listaTeste.Select(s => { s.Consulta = s.GetType().GetProperty(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name).GetValue(s); return s; }).OrderBy(x => x.Consulta).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;

    }
}


public class Teste
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Cidade { get; set; }
    public Object Consulta { get; set; }
}
```